# a PHP issue in LOCAL HOST / a "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required" occurs, directory problem

Tags: xampp, localhost

I'm new on this so thanks and sorry in advance

I'm having a issue trying to work with my localhost.
(not sure how to describe the problem)

im working with github, making some changes with VSCode, using XAMPP for localhost.

///The problem:

I was working fine with those files before but now there's a new line of code in files .php

```
"<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php');"
```

When opening the files on my localhost, page is not working and showing this issue.

```
Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\sections\hello-bar.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\sections\hello-bar.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\index.php(51): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\sections\hello-bar.php on line 2
```

-Already deal by the moment, the problem is I need to add in
"C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php'"
to be like this
C:/xampp/htdocs/POLYFEN/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php'

so my localhost need to declarate the root folder inside of "htdocs", meanwhile in liveserver this not required.
so the webpage works fine in github and in LiveServer, but now to work in my LocalHost have this problem where the directory path is different.
I have no idea is this is a xampp or localhost directory or how to proceed.

Hope someone understand with patient what is my problem.
It's not my code, a friend is helping me to learn but he don't know why this happen in my laptop so i need to find out myself.

*Thanks*

Lean B.

to work in my localHost i need to include a folder in the root.
and then take it away to push the changes into github.

This is how it work live
"C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php'"

and this is how i need to use to work in localHost
C:/xampp/htdocs/polyfen/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem I needed to create a Vhost for the specific project, another users told me that using one localhost for all is not a good setup. after creating a vhost with WAMP for the specific project, the issue dissapared. Because the project folder was in the end a subfolder of the root (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

```
   C:/xampp/htdocs/polyfen/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php'
```

maybe you move those files to
C:/xampp/htdocs/includes/DatesUtilsPolyfen.php'

because your polyfen part is different to the PHP environment.

You can use PHP's phpinfo() to check document root.

Comment: Hello, thanks for aswer.
In that case I understand that I need for my xampp or localhost to undertstand that the folder INCLUDES is inside of POLYFEN, meanwhile in the server local folder is polyfen and declaration of code start in ../includes.
when starting in localhost the root probably is htdocs and searching straight there, insteed of searching in root folder of project (polyfen) inside of htdocs. 
still not sure how to advance, but I need to modify this in my workstation, in the livehost and owners computer (who use xampp as my but in mac) is working properly.

Comment: yes the INCLUDES entry in PHP needs to point to the files you want to include which reside in the POLYFEN folder.  The main point is that PHP needs to know where the files are and this is set by telling PHP via the include directive where they are.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file you should see something like...

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
```

As per the above example you want to have:

```
include_path = .;c:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\includes\DatesUtilsPolyfen.php
```

This means that in the above example the  .;  uses your 'default includes' path and then adds the
'c:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\includes\DatesUtilsPolyfen.php' to the existing path to your includes.

On the other computers you want to do the same thing.
All PHP is wanting is that you tell it where the files to include actually are.

With PHP using:

```
<?php
  phpinfo()
?>
```

You can verify that php is in fact able to see the c:\xampp\htdocs\polyfen\includes
files and phpinfo() shows something like (in this case for pear):

```
include_path    .;C:\php\pear   .;C:\php\pear
```

If your path is correct and you still have a problem then it could be a security issue on your xampp folder. PHP may need to have the permission to use the folder.

Also Your log files will give you plenty of information on any errors if you have any.

In the php.ini file you can set the error logging level to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

This can be seen under the section "Error handling and logging" in the php.ini file.
So your log files hold the key to finding the point where php has raided the error.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer me, I tried to fix it using what you said, but as I couldn't,I ask about to my teamleader, and they decide to take out this php code atm... So now it's not an issue anymore. I know that there's chances this issue return so I will ask someone else about how to implement what you said, will update in any case. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. Good on you for persevering.

Comment: Hello, I just came to tell you that finally I fix it, i needed to create a Vhost for the project because the root folder was in the end htdocs and the project folder was like an subfolder.  after that did it work! greetings.

Comment: Also remember that the path delimiter varies accross different os's eg a / or a \